# Hibernate Problem in model class to map two tables

Tags: hibernate, model

> I want to to join two table using @ManyToOne relation. but i got this error given below. i have also posted the model Classes. How can i solve this error? and what is the problem here in my code due to this error is ocurring

.   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \
     \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)

```
2019-04-04 21:10:32.886  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] h.application.HandCraftApplication       : Starting HandCraftApplication on A-PC with PID 4708 (C:\Users\A\Desktop\STS\HandKart\target\classes started by A in C:\Users\A\Desktop\STS\HandKart)
2019-04-04 21:10:32.891  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] h.application.HandCraftApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-04-04 21:10:33.008  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-04-04 21:10:33.008  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-04-04 21:10:35.407  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-04-04 21:10:35.472  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 48ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-04-04 21:10:36.745  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d628b923] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-04-04 21:10:38.396  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2019-04-04 21:10:38.458  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-04-04 21:10:38.458  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
2019-04-04 21:10:38.484  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\JAVA\jre1.8.0_202\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_202/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_202/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_202/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\A\Downloads\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.7.RELEASE;;.]
2019-04-04 21:10:39.099  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2019-04-04 21:10:39.113  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-04-04 21:10:39.114  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6106 ms
2019-04-04 21:10:39.759  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-04-04 21:10:40.091  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-04-04 21:10:40.215  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-04-04 21:10:40.363  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
2019-04-04 21:10:40.366  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-04-04 21:10:40.728  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-04-04 21:10:41.066  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2019-04-04 21:10:41.585  WARN 4708 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: handkraft.application.model.ProductCatagory, at table: product, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(prod_cat)]
2019-04-04 21:10:41.587  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-04-04 21:10:41.600  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-04-04 21:10:41.608  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-04-04 21:10:41.629  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-04-04 21:10:41.639 ERROR 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: handkraft.application.model.ProductCatagory, at table: product, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(prod_cat)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at handkraft.application.HandCraftApplication.main(HandCraftApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: handkraft.application.model.ProductCatagory, at table: product, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(prod_cat)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: handkraft.application.model.ProductCatagory, at table: product, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(prod_cat)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:486) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:347) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:466) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

> Product Class

```
package handkraft.application.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class ProductModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Product name should not be blank")
    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;
    @NotBlank(message = "Produc Price shoud ot be blank")
    @Column(name = "product_price")
    private int productPrice;
    @NotBlank(message = "Product details should not be blank")
    @Column(name = "product_details")
    private String details;
    @NotBlank(message = "Product Quantity should not blank")
    @Column(name = "product_quantity")
    private int quantity;
    @Column(name = "product_store_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @NotBlank(message = "Date should not blank")
    private Date storeDate;


    private ProductCatagory prodCat;

    public ProductModel() {

    }

    public ProductModel(Long id, String productName, int productPrice, String details, int quantity, Date storeDate,
            ProductCatagory prodCat) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
        this.details = details;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.storeDate = storeDate;
        this.prodCat = prodCat;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public int getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(int productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Date getStoreDate() {
        return storeDate;
    }

    public void setStoreDate(Date storeDate) {
        this.storeDate = storeDate;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public ProductCatagory getProdCat() {
        return prodCat;
    }

    public void setProdCat(ProductCatagory prodCat) {
        this.prodCat = prodCat;
    }

}
```

> Product Category Class

```
package handkraft.application.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name="product_category")
public class ProductCatagory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="prod_cat_id")
    private Long categoryId;
    @NotBlank(message="Category name should not be blank")
    @Column(name="cat_name")
    private String categoryName;

    public ProductCatagory() {

    }

    public ProductCatagory(Long categoryId, String categoryName) {
        super();
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public Long getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(Long categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }


}
```

Comment: I have solved the problem by my own. Thank you

Comment: Instead of using @joincolumn annotation with the getter method i have used it with the variable and it is done. thank you